# How to redirect to another page while keeping the original url?

Tags: wicket-1.5, wicketstuff

In my Wicket 1.5 web application, I want to redirect to another bookmarkable page, whilst the **URL of the originating page should remain**.

```
@MountPath(value="page1")
public class WebPage1 extends WebPage {

    public WebPage1() {
        ...
        if (!isDisplayable()) {
            setResponsePage(WebPage2.class);
            // throw new RestartResponseException(Error404WebPage.class);
            // throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(Error404WebPage.class);
        }
    }

    private boolean isDisplayable() {
        boolean flag = ...
        ...
        return flag;
    }
}

@MountPath(value="page2")
public class WebPage2 extends WebPage {

    public WebPage2() {
    }

    public WebPage2(PageParameters params) {
    }
}
```

Neither of the approaches with setResponsePage(..), throw new RestartResponseException(..) or throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(..) leaves the URL unchanged.
All three methods redirect to Page2 **and** change the displayed URL in the browser's address bar.

Answer (score 0):

You should supply the `RestartResponseException` with  `RedirectPolicy.NEVER_REDIRECT`. I.e.

```
throw new RestartResponseException(new PageProvider(Error404Page.class), RedirectPolicy.NEVER_REDIRECT);
```