# How to server-side forward a page request with Wicket 6

Tags: wicket, forward

In some circumstances, I have to pass a request to a Wicket page to another Wicket page **on the server side**, i.e. **forward** maintaining the URL in the browser address bar, but passing the page parameters to the second page.

Before Wicket 1.5, I could do

```
public MyPage(PageParameters params) {
    // some logic here to decide whether and where to forward
    setRedirect(false);
    setResponsePage(MyOtherPage.class, params);
}
```

As `setRedirect(boolean)` no longer exists, is there a way to achieve a server-side forward in later Wicket versions?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822137/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-while-keeping-the-original-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague just found the solution here: 
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/wicket-users/201203.mbox/%3CCAMomwMr2fkO38E3d9RTk5TEmuf0Vx66F46F8eYs84Bb3bVtPgA@mail.gmail.com%3E

Now it is:

```
RequestCycle.get().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(new RenderPageRequestHandler(new PageProvider(MyOtherPage.class, params), RenderPageRequestHandler.RedirectPolicy.NEVER_REDIRECT));
```

Scary piece of code... does not look elegant at all, but works.

Answer (score 2):

On Wicket 6 you can redirect to another page in a simpler way, throwing `RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException` at any point in your page code:

```
throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(WicketPage.class)
```

It worked fine for me...

Comment: I assume that this would work, however throwing Exceptions is expensive and should not be part of normal program flow... but admittedly, I do not know how expensive above solution is in comparison. As far as I am concerned, the question is out of date anyway :)

Comment: That's true, maybe is not so bad for performance, but it's really awkward throwing exceptions to forward to another page, they should have kept the old method...

Comment: By using RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException, Wicket will keep track of the initial target page in the session and will send the user back to if if you do "org.apache.wicket.Component.continueToOriginalDestination()". This is appropriate when you want to interrupt the page rendering to send the user to a login page for example, but not if you just want to do a simple redirect. For a simple redirect, org.apache.wicket.RestartResponseException is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply do:

```
throw new RestartResponseException(MyOtherPage.class, params);
```